# Toggle latching IC to replace relay

Tags: relay, integrated-circuit, latch

I need an IC on which pins stays in same state after power reset. How it's called? I don't want to use relays.

Comment: It's basically a non-volatile memory. Whether you can get a single chip which places its remembered state directly onto one or more pins is another matter. Maybe an EE-Pot would do, if you only want one pin and don't mind a relatively complex IC for a mundane task. Maybe Dallas/Maxim have something that would do.

Comment: Your cheapest, most versatile solution is probably an MCU.

Comment: There is not enough information to provide you with a useful answer. How many "pins", what power / voltage supply are you talking about, do pin states need to be conserved with or without power applied etc ??